Dryer drum turns but heating element is cold. Which component do I need to replace?
Composite wiring diagram & back of dryer attached (cramped space, so couldn't get it all in one image). I suspect the thermal cutoff fuse needs replacement. Which component is that? I've numbered some suspects. Is it 1?


It is better to test than just replacing parts till it works again. Fuses are easy, they are open(bad) or close(good).  They are usually also cheapest part to replace.

My  experience is there are about 3 sensors, a fuse, and an element. that all have about the same life expectancy. And once you go to the trouble to shop, open, and replace the one part you don't want to go through that again, especially when you can usually get a kit with all the components for under $30. https://www.amazon.com/s?k=dryer+element+kit&crid=295JKF5NQT4L1&sprefix=dryer+element+kit%2Caps%2C176&ref=nb_sb_noss_1

I agree with @crip659. Get someone with a clur to use a multimeter to see how far power gets, and replace the last thing which got power but didn't pass it on when it should have. Test, don't guess, unless you want to waste time and money replacing the wrong parts. The failure may just be a wire, a connector, or a component.

Buy a cheap meter (under $10) and test each of the switches/fuses/sensors you see.  If you're comfortable with taking the cover off and replacing parts yourself, you can do this - and much more with the meter.  Do unplug the dryer first.  The meter has its own battery to check resistance and continuity.
Look up the make/model on parts suppliers websites, many have pix of the items and a pictorial showing where they are installed.  The easiest way to troubleshoot is to check each device you see, and if it's open, refer to the the pictorial to identify and order it.
